# Set microphone volume in C#

Tags: c#, audio, microphone

Is there a way to set the microphone volume in C# (normally done in control panel -> audio -> advanced, go to recording, and then dragging the slider)?  I only want to set it to maximum, if that makes it any easier.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a managed way to do this.  I would look into the winmm dll.  [Here is a link](http://www.pinvoke.net/search.aspx?search=winmm&namespace=winmm) to the available methods.

Also, [here's an example from CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/mixerSetControlDetails.aspx?fid=16481&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=26&select=959354) for how it could be used.